# Comma separated String values from a Vector

Tags: string, vector, clojure

I'm defining a vector containing string values. The requirement is to retrieve the String values separated by comma from the input vector. For example:

```
(def my-strings ["one" "two" "three"])
```

My expected output should be:

```
"one", "two", "three"
```

I tried `interpose` and `join` as shown below:

```
(apply str (interpose "," my-strings))
(clojure.string/join "," my-strings)
```

Both returning `"one,two,three"` but I need each string to be surrounded by double quotes `""` like in my example above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` to surround each string with quotes, and notice how we represent a single quote using `\"`, a character literal:

```
(clojure.string/join "," (map #(str \" % \") my-strings))
=> "one","two","three"
```

Be warned, though: a string is the text contained inside the `""` characters, but the quotes themselves are not part of the string. so the `"one,two,three"` output is not wrong per se, *unless* you really really need those extra quotes surrounding the text.

Comment: Character literals are also permitted if you want to save a few keystrokes: `... (map #(str \" % \") my-strings) ...`

Comment: Quote wrapping also happens to be the behavior of the object printer for strings: `(clojure.string/join "," (map pr-str my-strings))`.

Comment: Excellent!! That will do. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output in no way can be **"one", "two", "three"**. What type would it be, then? Dynamic types are not no-types. But, of course, you can have it as string. And this string has to be represented somehow in repl.

Also please remember that comma , in Clojure is whitespace.

Special characters, like ", shall be escaped. In this case: \".

The quotes that you see in repl are not parts of the string (unless escaped). The string is **one**, not **"one"**. If you want **"one"**, you see **"\"one\""**.

The Answer of Óscar is not precise. The code does not output what is shown there. It outputs **"\"one\",\"two\",\"three\""**. (You may add one extra space after , to exactly match your requirement.).

Nevertheless, his answer is **correct**: It gives you exactly what you want. It is a string consisting of a word **one** surrounded by double quotes and followed by a comma, etc.

Try to *spit* it into a file. I did (adding extra space after comma). The file had:

```
"one", "two", "three"
```

Cheers -

P.S. LightTable is AWESOME !!!

Answer (score 1):

The following also does the trick:

```
(let [strs ["one" "two" "three"]]
  (println
    ;;              outer quote       strings    outer quote
    (apply str (flatten [\" (interpose "\",\"" strs) \"]))))
```

Output:

```
user=> (let [strs ["one" "two" "three"]] (println (apply str (flatten [\" (interpose "\",\"" strs) \"]))))
"one","two","three"
nil
user=>
```